# Get Clicked Item in GridView within SemanticZoom

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a very basic SemanticZoom implementation within my Windows 8 app. This app has the following xaml:

```
<SemanticZoom x:Name="semanticZoom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsZoomedInViewActive="False">
  <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <GridView x:Name="myGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource orderViewSource}}" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="orderGridView_ItemClick">
    </GridView>
  </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

  ...
</SemanticZoom>
```

Oddly, the `orderGridView_ItemClick` event never fires when I click an item. I've heard that the semantic zoom control catches it, and doesn't bubble it down. If that's the case though, there should still be a way for me to see which item was selected. How do I determine what item an user clicks from the `ZoomedOutView` within a `SemanticZoom` control?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to know which item was clicked?  The SemanticZoom control should handle it automatically when you zoom in...